# connection error when creating app using cordova

Tags: vue.js, cordova

I was try to create android app using vuejs and cordova. A connection error shown while opening app.

my .env

```
VUE_APP_URL='https://myapp.com'
```

cordova/config.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.mealclub.app" version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>UkMeals</name>
    <description>
        A sample Apache Cordova application that responds to the deviceready event.
    </description>
    <author email="dev@cordova.apache.org" href="http://cordova.io">
        Apache Cordova Team
    </author>
    <!-- this hook will point your config.xml to the DevServer on Serve -->
    <hook type="after_prepare" src="../node_modules/vue-cli-plugin-cordova/serve-config-hook.js" />
    <content src="index.html" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <platform name="android">
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
    </platform>
</widget>
```

Error image

[image]

Comment: Check your network traffic for a more detailed error message

Comment: @Laurens just a look in to my .env fie. Server url is https://myapp.com . But error message shows localhost ip address.

Comment: Still need more information than 'the connection was unsuccessful'. Could be you don't have scheme/hostname defined which will defaults to "https:// localhost". In that case you're looking at CORS issues.

Comment: @Laurens Thank you for your valuable time.  If any cors issue , 'npm run cordova-serve-browser' will get error.?i am right .?But working perfect in browser.

Comment: You need more information why the request failed. It is important to know whether it is a 404, 500 or something completely different